# How show content based on Cookie value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I want to display product price in **USD** and **GBP**. My default currency is USD. If user come from UK ip range this script will set currency code GBP in cookie.

How to display price based on Cookie value(java-Script method)?

**script:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userip","asdfgh","userip");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = "SELECT id FROM ip WHERE '$ip' BETWEEN f AND t"; // check user ip from UK ip range
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  setcookie('currency', 'GBP', time()+604800);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in javascript, you can use the functions below to read/write a cookie.

```
function read_cookie(name) {
  var arg=name+"=";
  var alen=arg.length;
  var clen=document.cookie.length;
  var i=0;
  while (i<clen){
    var j=i+alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i, j)==arg)
       return arguments_cookie(j);
    i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
    if (i==0) break;
  }
  return null; 
}

function write_cookie(name, val, expires) {
  document.cookie=name+"="+escape(val)+
  ((expires==null) ? "" : ("; expires="+expires.toGMTString()));
}

function arguments_cookie(offset){
    var endstr=document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
    if (endstr==-1) endstr=document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read from $_COOKIE global var:

```
switch ($_COOKIE['currency']) {
  case "GBP": [...]; break;
   default: [...]
```

more details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Comment: Make sure you validate the cookie contents properly, they might very well be injected with malicious data, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can access cookies through `$_COOKIE`.

```
switch($_COOKIE['currency']) {
    case 'GBP':
        $price = <...>;
    break;

    // USD
    default:
    $price = <...>;
}
```

In JavaScript it's a bit different:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
    {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Note: users can changes cookies in their browser so be aware. A user might change currency to anything trying to break your script.

Comment: in java-script  method ?